# How can I do a vlookup in a new column with Python?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, vlookup

I am trying to create a new column in df1 with the "soll" values from df2 by the key "mittlere Wind". I've tried doing a vlookup and it works when I do it in a new df. Can someone help me by doing it in a new column in an existing df?

This works just fine:

```
results=df1.merge(df2,on='mittlere Wind', how='left')
```

When I try this, I get an error:

```
df1['soll']=df1['mittlere Leistung'].merge(df2['soll'],on='mittlere Wind', how='left')
Error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'merge'
```

Comment: ``merge`` is pandas dataframe function, ``df1['mittlere Leistung']`` will return series instead try ``df.merge(df2, on=[]...)``

Comment: _df1['soll']=df1.merge(df2,on='mittlere Wind', how='left')_ if I am doing this I will get the _mittlere Wind_ values in my new column

Answer (score 0):

You must make right side of '=' to series type in order to avoid not necessary column.
Refer to code below.  You can see ['C'] added for making them to series type.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame( { 'A' : [i for i in range(1,11,2)],
                      'B' : [3,5,2,4,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame( { 'A' : [i for i in range(1,11)],
                      'B' : [i for i in range(1,11)],
                      'C' : [4,5,7,9,20,4,5,3,4,10]})

df1['C'] = df1.merge(df2, on='A', how='left')['C']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I import the df from a csv file. 
I tried your option, with the ['C'] at the end of the line. But now I get the Error: _ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index_

Comment: You must add ['soll'] instead of 'C'

Comment: I did. `df1['soll']=(df1.merge(df2,on='mittlere Wind', how='left'),['soll'])` I get the Error: `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`